# How to add text there? (FlutterMap) Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SayB.png

how do I add text there?
I tried many things but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stack Widget Like below

[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stac…](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stac%E2%80%A6)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
  children:  [
    FluterMap(...),
    Text('Your text')
   ]
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need wrap your FlutterMap inside Stack widget, like this.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
   [
    FluterMap(...),
    Text('Your text')
   ]
  )
);
```